# How to compile typescript with babel 7 cli?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, babel-loader

This:

```
babel ./src/MyTypescript.ts  --out-dir ./wwwroot/js/
```

doesn't work (no error, just '0 compiled').

`.babelrc` contains everything that Babel 7 need to compile typescript with webpack babel loader: preset "@babel/typescript" and plugin "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties" (pair which works for me with current babel 7 rc01).

Comment: Why do you want to use babel with typescript? Why don't you simply use typescript compiler?

Comment: just for research and debugging (it is quite complex to extract transpiled TS code from bundle)

Comment: I would be very happy if somobody could certainly explain me that @babel/typescript is wrong (or good) idea. Now this dilemma "what to use tsc or preset" - paralyze me.

Comment: @AkashKava: [this post](https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/) details why you'd want to use just Babel 7, without TypeScript (but with the TypeScript plugin) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an answer:

```
 babel ./src/MyTypescript.ts  --out-dir ./wwwroot/js/ --extensions '.ts,.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer did not work for me.

I've solved with the help of the following link:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Babel-Starter/blob/master/package.json

`"build:js": "babel src --out-dir lib --extensions \".ts,.tsx\" --source-maps inline"`

To add the TS extensions:

`--extensions \".ts,.tsx\"`